# PHP Create an array from fetch array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, fetch

I have a Mysql query that gives the following result as using
`while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))`

`x | 12432`

`y | 232432`

`z | 323423`

I want to take each column and put it in a new array in order to export them in a table that would look like

`x   |    y   |   z`

`12432 | 232432 | 323423`

If I fetch the same query more than once, the second row does not show up.

Can you please help?

Comment: You should try to use mysqli or PDO for your database connections.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: Switch to mysqli (or PDO) as soon as you can! Plenty of reasons can be found in searchengines, so im gonna leave that to you.**

---

You can use a nested loop to do this:

```
$array = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
    foreach($res as $key=>$value){
        $array[$key][] = $value;
    }
}
```

The first round of the while will give the $array the key-names and their first value, the next litterations through the loop will only add values

Answer (score 1):

That is the code that worked for me.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){

    $clients[] = $row[0];

    $stats[] = $row[1];

}

foreach ($clients as $client)
{
    echo "<td>$client</td>";
}

echo "</tr><tr>";

foreach ($stats as $stat)
{
    echo "<td>$stat</td>";
}
```

Comment: However, there is a problem. It does not display the first entries in each array.